# c# permissions on a specific service restart operation

Tags: c#, permissions, admin

I have c# code that needs to stop "some_service":

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("some_service");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult =
        MessageBox.Show("You need to stop some_service. May I stop some_service?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        try
        {
            sc.Stop();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to stop some_service - You need administrator permissions for that. " + ex.Message,
                "Error while trying to stop some_service", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

It fails due to permission problems:

```
Cannot open some_service service on computer '.'.
StackTrace = "   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Stop()
at LocalTraceView.Form1.btnSendCapture_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I tried 2 things:
method 1: indicating the method to be run as admin by adding

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
```

which resulted in an error:

```
{"Request for principal permission failed."}
```

sorry, that's all the error I can see.
Method 2: I open the property window in visual studio and selected security: Enable ClickOnce security settings
and marked "This is a full trust application"
and that did not help.
Given that I have not and do not want to sign this binary, is there a way to allow it run as admin? I prefer to pop the admin permission window at run time as needed but if I have to pop it at the very beginning of starting the app, that's fine as well.

Note: my point is that the user must get the popup admin permission window to be able to allow stopping of the service.

The contents of app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Also, I've tried adding:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

to app.manifest while turning off ClickOnce, I get an error while compiling:

> The application has failed to start because the application
>   configuration is incorrect.

Update: after reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vb.ProjectPropertiesSecurity.HowTo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true
I realized that the ClickOnce option will take effect upon installation. Tested it with installation. It works meaning that the installed software can stop the service, but it's not working within visual studio while developing.

Comment: can you show what the .config file settings looks like is there an `Authentication` section or setting

Comment: you need to show that in your original question just edit your own question and post it properly please..